# Duplicate records after Section Expert activation

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

<strike>Something weird (or maybe not that weird) happened today when trying to finish this report, report I was supposed to handle to the client today. Regardless</strike>

I have created two detailed sections with suppression rules.

section A has `IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "0" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE /*only records with siege_hr =0 will be shown*/`

section B has `IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "1" AND {ELEC_ENQUETES2.FLG_SIEGE}="0" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE /*only records with siege_hr =1 and FLG_SIEGE=0  will be shown*/`

Put separately, section A shows me 10897 records and section B shows me 2208 records. Each section brings unique records. When combine , the records should be still unique and gives me the sum of the records from the 2 sections e.g 13102.

Yet, when I'm running the report with the 2 sections , I have duplicate records, close to a thousand, which gives me in total 14015 records.

I made sure to select in the database tab , distinct records only ... to no avail.

I'm slowly but certainly losing my sanity ...

Any insights are welcomed

Comment: do you have the same fields in both sections? if so why you don't combine the 2 suppression rules in 1 using an else if

Comment: Hi @cojimarmiami, I don't have the same fields in the 2 sections. This is the reason why I have 2 separate sections

Comment: so if you suppress section A, do you get the right amount of records for section B and vice-versa?

Comment: @cojimarmiami how do I save date ?

Comment: click on file and select save data with report

Comment: write this on section A {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} <> "0" and this on section B {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} <> "1" AND {ELEC_ENQUETES2.FLG_SIEGE}<>"0". do not add any if else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102015/discussion-between-cojimarmiami-and-andy-k).

Comment: Put section A Separately (Two different report) and find the difference. A) IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "0" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE   B) IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "0" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE AND {ELEC_ENQUETES2.FLG_SIEGE}="0"    Get Record difference of A and B

Comment: Hi @Sivaraman, thanks for your help. Lack of time to update everything but I'm catching up , finally. Cojimarmiami helps me a big deal to fix my issue and with his help, I was able to find out the solution. It was a condition

Comment: @Silverlightfox awesome outfit ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the solution , thanks to @cojimarmiami

I added an extra condition on both detailed sections , `AND {ELEC_.FLG_SIEGE} ="1"` for details A and  `AND {ELEC_.FLG_SIEGE}<>"1"`for details B.

Which gives this

> Details A

```
IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "0" AND {ELEC_.FLG_SIEGE} ="1" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE //(for details A)
```

> Details B

```
IF {ELEC_.SIEGE_HR} = "1" AND {ELEC_.FLG_SIEGE}<>"1" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE //(for details B)
```